# What does `print` interprete as whitespace?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the complete list of whitespace characters that `print` interprets as such?

I need to truly understand how the `print` statement works in Python. So far so weird, but this is one detail that I can't figure out:

In Python's reference manual chapter 6.6 it says:

> ... when the last character written to standard output is a whitespace character except ' ',  ...

I know that the most common whitespace for this case is '\n', but I need to know the others.

Comment: May be you want this: `import string;print repr(string.whitespace)`.

Comment: I'd suggest trying to find a solution that doesn't require using that obscure part of the `print` statement's semantics. For instance, joining various substrings together into a single output string (that you have full control over). Or try `from __future__ import print_function` for a forwards compatible approach (which always includes its `sep` parameter between its arguments, even if they end in whitespace).

Comment: @Blckknght I coudn't agree more. However, I have to reproduce the print statement's behaviour exactly. Not that I'd encourage anyone of depending on it.

Comment: I believe this is what was called the "soft-space" feature of `print`, which was removed in python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CPython, it is probably all characters for which [isspace()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) returns `true`, namely:

- `\f` (form feed)
- `\n` (linefeed)
- `\r` (carriage return)
- `\t` (horizontal tab)
- `\v` (vertical tab)